# How can I count, filter, and collect an iterator in a single pass?

Tags: rust, functional-programming, iterator

I would like to count an iterator, filter it, and collect the filter in a single iteration.

I can't find any zero cost abstractions that allow me to do that. Using a loop I can achieve that in a single loop. As far as i know using iterator adapters I need two loops.

I don't know how a high level API for this would even look. Something like a lazy fold, so that adapters applied after return a composite result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```rust
let mut counter = 0;
iterator.inspect(|_| counter += 1).filter(|v| /* condition */).collect();
```

Comment: Somehow I've haven't used inspect so far. Thanks :)

Comment: @PrancingCrabulon It is possible to implement this without `inspect()`, with `map(|v| { counter += 1; v })`.

Comment: `filter` also takes an `FnMut` so the counter could also be incremented as part of the filter function. Yet an other option would be to `fold` into a state containing both a counter and a vector (to conditionally collect into). Some might view this as "less imperative".

Answer (score 2):

Being a bit of a functional nerd I'd use a good old `fold`:

```rust
let (count, filtered) = iterator.fold((0, Vec::new()), |(n, mut v), e| {
    if /* condition */ { v.push(e); }
    (n+1, v)
});
```